# Is there a way to add bold styling to part of a Word VBA combobox text entries?

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word, styles

I have a macro enabled word template with a user form combo box that I need to have some of the text that it inserts to show as bold on the document. I tried just adding html elements such as  bold html but they didn't work. Is there a way to style parts of the text when it is inserted?

```
'Populate standard_response
  With standard_response
  .AddItem "<b><u>You were not provided written notice of charge.</u></b> You signed for and received a copy of the offense report detailing the charge against you on 00/00/00.  You also verbally acknowledged during your disciplinary hearing on 00/00/00 that you received a copy of the offense report"
   .AddItem "You were not provided at least 24 hours to prepare before hearing.  You received a copy of the offense report detailing the charge against you on 00/00/00.  Your disciplinary hearing was conducted on 00/00/00, therefore, you had at least twenty-four hours to prepare for the hearing.   "
   .AddItem "You were not permitted the opportunity to present relevant witness/es or to submit relevant written witness statements.  During the active phase of the investigation you did not wish to call any witnesses as verified by your signature on the 'Disciplinary Coordinator's Report' on 7/19/19.  You were also provided with the opportunity to present relevant written witness statements at your disciplinary hearing but did not do so."
   .AddItem "There was no written statement of evidence utilized for a determination of guilt.  Section III of the 'Disciplinary Hearing Report' cites a written statement of evidence relied on for the finding of guilt that identifies the offending behavior and is compliant with Section VII.D.2. of OP-060125, 'Offender Disciplinary Procedures.' "
  End With
```

Comment: Neither userforms nor Word documents use HTML styling in their native formats. Your code sample appears to be trying to set part of the combo box display to appear in bold, while your text states you want the text in the final document to be bold. The latter is possible, but not the former.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to run a macro that would highlight part of the text depending on the dropdown choice used. But simpler ways include 1 - saving it as AutoText/Building Block within the template, then using the dropdown choice to insert the relevant text block or 2 - formatting all the choices, marking them as hidden text, then revealing just the chosen response. All 3 scenarios are illustrated:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim oTextRange As Range
    Set oTextRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Response").Range
    Select Case standard_response.value
        Case "Item 1"
            With oTextRange
                .Text = standard_response.value
                .MoveEnd Unit:=wdWord, Count:=30
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
        Case "Item 2"
            ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries("Response1").Insert Where:=oTextRange, RichText:=True
        Case "Item 3"
            ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Response1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
        Case Else
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great.